# Serialization between WCF and Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, serialization

I need an expert's help. I have a custom class called MyException. The purpose of this class is to log exceptions with custom information. The definition of this class is as shown here:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyException
{
  [DataMember]
  public string StackTrace { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string Message { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string Component { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string TypeName { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string Miscellaneous { get; set; }

  public MyException() 
  {}

  public MyException(string message)
  {
    this.Message = message;
  }

  public MyException(string message, string stackTrace)
  {
    this.Message = message;
    this.StackTrace = stackTrace;
  }
}
```

I have a WCF service that is intended to accept a MyException in JSON format and write it's contents to a database. Because of the amount of information I intend to track, I need to use a POST operation, so I decided to base my implementation [off this blog post](http://technicalitiesblog.blogspot.com/2010/03/using-get-post-in-silverlight-restful.html). My service description can be found here:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/LogError", Method="POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string LogError(Stream stream)
{
  try
  {
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = 
      new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyException));
    MyException exception = (MyException)(serializer.ReadObject(stream));
    // Write the exception details to the database
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Write the exception details to the database
  }
}

[OperationContract]
public void Test(MyException exception)
{ }
```

I added the "Test" operation so that the MyException would be exposed during proxy generation to my Silverlight application. My Silverlight application attempts to post to LogError using the following code:

```
MyServiceProxy.MyException exception = new MyServiceProxy.MyException();
exception.Message = e.Error.Message;
exception.StackTrace = e.Error.StackTrace;
exception.Component = GetComponentName();
exception.TypeName = e.Error.FullName;

string json = string.Empty;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new 
    DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyServiceProxy.MyException));
  serializer.WriteObject(stream, exception);

  stream.Position = 0;
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }

  Uri uri = new Uri("/myService.svc/LogError", UriKind.Absolute);
  WebClient myService = new WebClient();
  myService.UploadStringCompleted += 
    new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(myService_UploadStringCompleted);
  myService.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  myService.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  myService.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", json);
}
```

When I run this code, I get an error in my Silverlight app that says:
"Type 'MyServiceProxy.MyException' with data contract name 'MyException:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel and you do not derive your custom Exception from System.Exception !?

Comment: @Davide Piras: .NET exceptions are **not** good for WCF communication - WCF comm should be interoperable and should use SOAP faults only (which often come with a custom class to hold more detailed error info)

Comment: Hi, didn't know that, I always thought .NET Exceptions are serializable anyway by design so should be ok to use them :)

Comment: Is there any reason why you are handling the serialization yourself and not letting WCF do it? (you could have a MyException parameter in your service instead of taking a stream)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that your type is different, you are using the proxy class and serializing it, and then trying to deserialize it as a different type when you get it back on the server side.

You should be able to add the KnownType attribute, I believe this would be needed on the auto generated proxy class.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how they are different types. If the Service Proxy is generating it based on the definition of the service, shouldn't it be the same thing?

Comment: They are in a different namespace, one is the concrete implementation the other is an auto generated proxy, which resembles the object but isn't the same.  You can get WCF/Silverlight to share the same object, but it requires creating more projects to share between the two.

Comment: Is there another way to do this? Or is this the only way to go. It just seems odd that I can't easily serialize this to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you explicitly set the namespace on the DataContract attribute. 
Something like `[DataContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/2010/etc")]` so the serializer would treat the classes as being the same.

I would give it a try. Adding the namespace and regenerating the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You specify in the request that the content-type of the request is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". But the content is actually JSON (generated using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`). Try updating the content-type to the correct one ("application/json") and that should get you further where you need to be.